# UAC dialog pops up when starting Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, uac

I use Windows 7, and Google Chrome 7. Every time I start Google Chrome, a UAC Dialog box pops up with the question:

> Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer?

It hasn't always been like this, only with the most recent version of Google Chrome. How can I get rid of this UAC pop up, without inactivating UAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try right hand click properties on the google icon, properties then compatibility. then uncheck run this program as administrator.

I know you did not want to turn off UAC, but turn off UAC run Google chrome as admin then turn on UAC.

Comment: "Uncheck run this program as administrator" solved this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have installed the Flash add-on and gave it elevated access, for example if you let it have webcam access.

Answer (score 0):

It wants to update itself (which happens silently).

I cannot locate an option for turning this off.  Perhaps an uninstall + reinstall allows things to get straightened up.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome properies > Compatibility > Look for a box that says "Run this program in compatibility mode for" then on the drop down choose win7

Answer (score -1):

I have had to change the default fonts so that various webpages display properly.  Perhaps having Google change fonts everytime I open a new tab or window requires the "changes to computer" popup.